# Rust async function parameters and lifetimes

Tags: rust

I'd like to understand why test1 causes an error but test2 compiles.

It seems like rust is being clever, and realising that when the .await is called directly on the async function result it knows to keep the parameter around for execution of the future but when the async is called on a separate line it can't do this.

Would love to have a link to the relevant functionality that makes this work to learn the details.

```
async fn do_async_thing(s: &String) {
    println!("{s}");
}

fn get_string() -> String {
    "sf".to_string()
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn test1() {
    let a = do_async_thing(&get_string());
    a.await;
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn test2() {
    do_async_thing(&get_string()).await;
}
```

The error

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> crates/dynamo/src/error.rs:11:29
   |
11 |     let a = do_async_thing(&get_string());
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                             |
   |                             creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
12 |     a.await;
   |     - borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly to do with `async`, its because the future returned from `do_async_thing` holds the string reference.

You can create your own future with the same result

```
struct DoAsyncThingFuture<'a> {
    s: &'a String
}
impl<'a> Future for DoAsyncThingFuture<'a> {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        println!("{}", self.s);
        Poll::Ready(())
    }
}

fn do_async_thing(s: &String) -> DoAsyncThingFuture {
    DoAsyncThingFuture {
        s
    }
}
```

And even get the same result without a future

```
fn do_sync_thing(s: &String) -> &String {
    s
}
```

Attempting to use the return value from either of these functions will give the same error. This happens the return value of `get_string` does not have an owner so it is dropped after the call to `do_sync_thing` witch means the return reference is dangling. So as why one works and the other does not:

```
let a = do_sync_thing(&get_string());
println!("{}", a);

//Same as 

let _temp_value = get_string();
let a = do_async_thing(&_temp_value);
drop(_temp_value);
println!("{}", a);
```

vs

```
println!("{}", do_sync_thing(&get_string()));

//Same as 

let _temp_value = get_string();
println!("{}", do_async_thing(&_temp_value));
drop(_temp_value);
```

Comment: I think what’s different in your example is using the result of the do* function. The snippet I posted has a function that returns nothing. For the async version the future is just used to await but no reference to the param is being returned

Comment: @Daniel `async` functions return a future, and that future holds the string reference . The `do_async_thing` function in my answer is essentially the de-sugared form of the `async` function in your question.

Comment: I see. So does this mean that the rust compiler is essentially line/statement oriented with regards to dropping the temp valuesEg: the drop happens after the line where the function call happens so as long as you are chaining calls in the same statement the reference lives?

Comment: @Daniel its more so that temporary values are dropped after the statement they are used in, and in this case each line is a statement.

Comment: thanks for the explanations!
If you happen to know, do you have a reference to the section of the rust docs talking about how temporary variable lifetimes are handled and when they're dropped? Would love to read the technical docs to see how its defined.

Edit: Answering my own question - here! https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html